# Find a fixed point formulation so that the fixed point iteration converges.

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration

I have been asked to 'find a fixed point formulation so that the fixed point iteration converges' for

$$x = \frac{2-e^x+x^2}{3}.$$

I'm confused how to do it because past examples have had something like 'in [2,3]' but this question does not have that! How do i complete this question?

Comment: I edited your question so that the math is typeset in MathJax. This is a pretty easy example and it's well worth learning.

Comment: The point to the problem is that, if you iterate the function $f(x) = (2-e^x+x^2)/3$ starting from, say, $x_0=1.0$, you generate a sequence of numbers that converges to a solution of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is

$$x^2-3x+2-e^x=0$$
by MVT, There is a solution in $[0,1] .$

it can be written as
$$x=g (x)=\frac {x^2-e^x+2}{3} .$$
it is easy to check that $$g ([0,1]\subset [0,1] .$$

$$g'(x)=\frac {2x-e^x}{3} $$

but
$0 <x <1 \implies 0 <2x <2 $ and $-e <-e^x<-1$
thus
$$\frac {-e}{3}<g'(x)<\frac {1}{3} $$
and
$$|g'(x)|<\frac {e}{3}<1$$
from here
we are sure that the recurrent sequence

$$x_0\approx \frac 12$$
$$x_{n+1}=g (x_n) $$ will converge to the root.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks for the remark. +1. i edited.

Comment: Thanks! But where does the -e/3 come from?

Comment: from inequality  $(0-e)/3$